# ./Reducers' does not contain an export named 'rootReducer'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

> I am getting this error while importing the reducer.

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from  'redux';
import {rootReducer } from './Reducers';
const store = createStore(rootReducer);

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

**Reducers/Reducer_placeorder .js**

```
    export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PLACE_ORDER":
      return action.payload;
  }

  return state;
}
```

**Reducers/index.js**

```
    import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import Reducer_placeorder from "./Reducer_placeorder";


const rootReducer  = combineReducers({
  data: Reducer_placeorder

})

export default rootReducer;
```

> while running i am getting the error does not contain an export named
>   'rootReducer'
>
> i have tried to import as "import {reducer } from './Reducers';" ,
>   still i get the error does not contain export named 'reducer'

Comment: remove the `{}`, like this: `import rootReducer from './Reducers';`